# Veracrypt windows partition encryption (FULL C DRIVE ENCRYPTION) with batch file (PowerShell command line)

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, encryption, veracrypt

I have crawled the whole net and havent been able to find the answer. I am trying to encrypt encrypt the c drive via VeraCrypt using a batch script.

`'C:\Program Files\veracrypt\VeraCrypt Format.exe' /create normal /size 50G /password Somepassword12** /hash sha512 /encryption AES /quick /dynamic /force`The above command just creates a locked volume named normal . I am trying to give the "encrypt the system or entire system drive" command as shown in[img][1] please help.

Comment: The command you have issued is working as intended by creating a 50 GB encrypted container.  Why don’t you use the installer (and/or GUI) to encrypt the desired volume? You are running the incorrect command of you want to encrypt an entire mounted volume. Where did you get this incorrect volume from?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help . I am trying to utilize it in a an application, thereby the process must be automated (without gui) .   I am aware the command is not for this purpose, I was just trying to show the syntax(perhaps someone could have picked up on it and figured out the right parameters) . After reading a few documents, I am afraid that system encryption was not implemented through cmd . The source code must be modified for that..

Comment: Seems a commentary of mine might have been deleted. If it was a can no longer help